# Мутация состояния внутри другой мутации?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Каким образом мне в мутация делать ещё одну мутацию
Поставить isAuth = true

```
 state: {
    isAuth: false,
    token: localStorage.getItem('retriewToken') || null
},
mutations: {
    retriewToken(state, token) { // мутация токена
        state.token = token
        console.log(token);
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Изменять isAuth в мутации retriewToken

   ```
   retriewToken(state, token) { // мутация токена
      state.token = token;
      state.isAuth = true;
      console.log(token);
   },
   ```
2. Cоздать мутацию которая работает с isAuth и вызвать ее в retriewToken

   ```
   retriewToken(state, token) { // мутация токена
      state.token = token;
      this.commit('setIsAuth', true);
      console.log(token);
   },
   setIsAuth(state, value) {
      state.isAuth = value;
   },
   ```

Comment: Я не понимаю почему но, по умолчанию сначала у меня isAuth: false, когда я логинюсь он стаёт в false, хотя у меняю в true. Значит потом я перехожу на странницу юзера - смотрю его данные - а isAuth - false. Перезагрузил ручками приложения (F5). - и состояния стало в isAuth : true. Почему? У меня что нету реактивности .....